# Extend model with custom function in mixin in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How in Loopback I can extend model with custom function in mixin?

I have:

common/models/user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "mixins": {
    "ModelRest": {}
  },
  ...
}
```

common/mixins/model-rest.js

```
module.exports = function (Model) {


  Model.hello = function() {
    console.log('hello!');
  };
 ...

}
```

But in common/models/user.js

```
module.exports = function (User) {

  User.hello();
  ...
}
```

I've got error:

> TypeError: User.hello is not a function

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: On your user model, you have to use `user` in lower case. Here have an example: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-mixins

Comment: I don't want to use function for instance, I want to use it for model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixins added to model after model setup. You call `hello` in setup phase.

The correct one is :

```
module.exports = function (User) {

  User.SomeMethod = function(){
    User.hello();
  }             
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

two ways to access methods of other models :

1. base model : in your case set base model of user as model-rest.
2. User.app.models.ModelRest.hello();